# Check if a character is Unicode in a way compatible with Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

**EDIT**: Clarifying the allowed character set based on comments

The allowed characters from ASCII character set are `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `-`, `_`, `.`, `/`. Any other character from ASCII set should not be allowed.

Unicode characters apart from the disallowed ASCII set defined above are also allowed.

**End of Edit**

I am processing some text data where the only allowed ASCII characters are `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and `-`,`_`,`.`,`/`. Apart from these Unicode characters are also allowed. I need to make sure that the incoming data contains only these set of characters.

Checking for the allowed ASCII characters is easy:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
VALID_CHARSET= set(ascii_letters + digits + "-_./")

def is_valid_string(string):
    for c in string:
        if c not in VALID_CHARSET:
            return False
    return True
```

But I am wondering about how to allow unicode characters apart from the above. I guess in Python-2.7 I could add a check like so:

```
if isinstance(c, unicode)
    return True
if c not in VALID_CHARSET:
    return False
```

But strings in Python-3 are Unicode by default and there is no separate `unicode` type, so this would not work there. Any cleaner way of doing this which works in both the versions of Python?

Comment: *"Apart from these Unicode characters are also allowed*" – Since Unicode encompasses *every possible character*, that is… rather broad.

Comment: Considering Unicode includes all of ASCII (at the same code points), I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to _eliminate_ only characters that are ASCII but not in your whitelist?

Comment: I made an attempt to clarify it

Comment: The easiest approach is probably to make a `set` of *forbidden* characters for testing, not *valid* ones (creating the set of valid ones only to aid with building the invalid set). Define `INVALID_CHARSET = frozenset(map(chr, range(128))) - VALID_CHARSET`, then your `is_valid_string` function can simplify to `return INVALID_CHARSET.isdisjoint(string)` (`set`/`frozenset`'s `isdisjoint` method is by far the most efficient means of checking for the presence of a forbidden character, as it short-circuits, makes no temporaries, and runs entirely at the C layer when the values are built-in types).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! That looks like it will work. I would accept it if the question was open. Also, thanks for the tip on isdisjoint, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvotes on the question? I added clarification based on the comments and I believe it was clear enough that ShadoRanger was able to answer it. It was perhaps an easy question in the hindsight but is that a reason to downvote?

Comment: @ShadowRanger The question is open for answer, if you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the question, you want to allow any non-ASCII character, plus the whitelisted ASCII characters. Since making a set of all valid characters is impractical (it would have over a million entries), the simplest solution is to make a set of invalid characters and verify that your strings contain none of them:

```
VALID_CHARSET = frozenset(ascii_letters + digits + "-_./")
INVALID_CHARSET = frozenset(map(chr, range(128))) - VALID_CHARSET
```

Once you have that, `is_valid_string` becomes trivial:

```
def is_valid_string(string):
    return INVALID_CHARSET.isdisjoint(string)
```

If you felt like it, you could even avoid defining the Python level function at all, saving a little call overhead (at the expense of not being able to define your own docstring) by just making an alias to the bound `isdisjoint` method:

```
is_valid_string = INVALID_CHARSET.isdisjoint
```

You're not going to get any faster than that; [`set`/`frozenset`'s `isdisjoint` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) pushes all the work to the C layer (no bytecode processing overhead per character), short-circuits (as soon as an invalid character is seen, it returns immediately), and performs each lookup in ~`O(1)` (so testing a string is `O(n)` in the length of the string).

If you aren't concerned with *checking*, but rather, want to strip out invalid characters, you'd want to use `str.translate`/`unicode.translate` to bulk delete the invalid characters, but given the API differs between the types (Py3 `str` and Py2 `unicode` use one form, Py3 `bytes` and Py2 `str` another), you'd have to go to some trouble to make it work on Py2 and Py3 on the same code base.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate the tips on performance side of it.